# UIImageView not set the image unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to set image in viewcontroller method setImage(index : Int) like this

```
(UIImage.image = UIImage(named : imageArray[index]))
```

and call this method in another controller like this

```
(objViewController.setImage(5))
```

but in setImage method give me an error on this line

```
(UIImage.image = UIImage(named : imageArray[index]))
```

the error is **unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**
sample of

Comment: `var image  = UIImage(named : imageArray[index])`

and you have to be sure that imageArray[index] contains a String, not a nil

Comment: Yes, I'm sure string not nil

Comment: but why are you doing `UIimage.image = ...`? assign the image to the  property of the view controller just with `imageProperty =  UIImage(named : imageArray[index])` And are you sure that you have an Image in your bundle with the correct name?

Comment: Is that your real code? `UIImage.image = ...` should not compile at all.

Comment: Problem occur when another controller set image. Within same controller its work

Comment: i'm using self.UIImageView.image = UIImage(named : imageArray[index]) in code. And image bundle is the correct name

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
UIImage.image =  imageArray(index)
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer. Didn't downvote btw.

Comment: (UIImage.image = UIImage(named : imageArray[index]))
 this is the not the way to fetch image from imageArray. The correct way is stated above. For further query you can check this http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18762

Comment: Swift array subscripts use square brackets: `imageArray[index]`. And `UIImage.image = ...` does not compile.

Comment: i'm using self.UIImageView.image = UIImage(named : imageArray[index]) in code